# Using @material-ui/core/Dialog to create custom alerts

Tags: beginner, react.js, jsx

I'm pretty new to using React Js and I am wondering how people with proper React JS experience would consider this code. Are my function names correct, am I following best practices, also does it seem to be easily maintainable? Thanks!

The dialogs sole purpose is to alert the user whether or not the email they entered is already used by another user or if their post request is successful.

I posted the Dialog itself below, and also the entire page so there is proper context.

**Dialog**

```
            <Dialog open={openDialog} onClose={handleCloseDialog}>
                <DialogTitle>{"title"}</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                    <DialogContentText>
                        {dialogText}
                    </DialogContentText>
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                    <button onClick={handleCloseDialog} autoFocus>Close</button>
                </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
```

**Entire code**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import DialogContentText from "@material-ui/core/DialogContentText";
import DialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";
import DialogActions from "@material-ui/core/DialogActions";
import DialogContent from "@material-ui/core/DialogContent";

import Loader from "../../assets/Button";
import handleSaveUser from "../hooks/handleSaveUser";

const NewsLetterForm = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [openDialog, setOpenDialog] = useState(false);
    const [dialogText, setDialogText] = useState("");
    const [postParams, setPostParams] = useState({
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        email: "",
    });

    const handleCloseDialog = () => { setOpenDialog(false); };

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setLoading(true);
        const formData = new FormData(e.target);
        const object = {
            firstName: formData.get("firstName") ?? "",
            lastName: formData.get("lastName") ?? "",
            email: formData.get("email") ?? "",
        }
        setPostParams(postParams);
        const apiResponse = await handleSaveUser("newsletter__form", object);

        setDialogText(apiResponse);
        setOpenDialog(true);
        setLoading(false);
    };

    return (
        <form
            id='newsletter__form'
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        >
            <label htmlFor='firstName' />
            <input
                name='firstName'
                className='__input'
                type='text'
                id='firstName'
                placeholder='First Name'
                required
            />
            <label htmlFor='lastName' />
            <input
                name='lastName'
                className='__input'
                type='text'
                id='lastName'
                placeholder='Last Name'
                required
            />
            <label htmlFor='email' />
            <input
                name='email'
                className='__input'
                type='text'
                id='email'
                placeholder='Email'
                required
            />
            <button
                disabled={loading}
                type="submit"
                value="Subscribe"
            >{loading ? <Loader /> : <>Subscribe</>}
            </button>
            <Dialog open={openDialog} onClose={handleCloseDialog}>
                <DialogTitle>{"Some Title"}</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                    <DialogContentText>
                        {dialogText}
                    </DialogContentText>
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                    <button onClick={handleCloseDialog} autoFocus>Close</button>
                </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
        </form>
    );
};

export default NewsLetterForm;
```

Comment: Hello, please take note that we'll be happy to review your current code. Or your refactored code when you have it. However we will not refactor your code for you. That's outside the scope of this site.

Comment: Hi @slepic, I’ll head over to stack overflow and reformat my question. On the other hand, if you would review it, what would you improve?

Comment: Could you please add a short description of what the code is for?  The description doesn't really explain why someone might want to use this code.

Comment: @TobySpeight just updated!